# Mulitple event selection on full calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-4

Just started using full calendar and its great.  Really easy to follow the documentation and very happy with it.  Got a nice timeline view displaying through json.

I've been Googling around for a while now a for a way to be able to click on an event in the calendar and put it into a shopping basket so to speak.

This way you could click many events from the calendar and then perform actions on them simultaneously.  I have a project that really could benefit from this feature.

Does anybody know if this already exists or if somebody has achieved this some how?  Maybe by control clicking events or simply clicking on each one and adding it to a list of events recently clicked?

Thanks

Comment: well the [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick) callback lets you detect when the user selected a single event, yes. You could then add it to your "basket" (however you've implemented that) after it's clicked. There's no way currently to select multiple events in one action (e.g. by dragging the mouse or something), if that's what you're asking.

Comment: @ADyson thanks for your response.  I might ask for that sort of feature to be put on the list if people think its a good idea.

Comment: If you go on the fullCalendar site there are instructions about making a feature request. I'm nothing to do with the project but it sounds like it good be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd post my solution to this problem.  Thanks to @ADyson for pointing me in the right direction.

so, first of all, you need a switch on the page that, if set to on changes the default behavior of the onclick for full calendar.

```
<label>
 <input type="checkbox" name="bulkSelect" id="bulkSelect" data-toggle="toggle">
            Bulk Select
</label>
```

Next, just before your full calendar call add the following lines of code in script tags.  A blank array and two functions.  One for adding to the array and one for removing from the array.

```
var myEvents = [];

function addToEventArray(element)
{
  myEvents.push(element);
}

function removeAFromArray(arr)
{
  var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
  while (L > 1 && arr.length)
  {
      what = a[--L];
      while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1)
      {
          arr.splice(ax, 1);
      }
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Now for the event click in full calendar.  The event click simply checks if the bulk select is set to checked.  if so then each new event you click will be added to the array of selected events.  It also puts a red border around events that are selected.  If you click the event for a second time the event is removed from the array and the border is removed.

Just to note I'm using extendedProps.eventID which is a custom field allowing me to give each new event its own unique ID.

```
eventClick: function(info) {
    if($('#bulkSelect').prop('checked') == true)
    {
      if(jQuery.inArray(info.event.extendedProps.eventID, myEvents) != -1)
      {
          removeAFromArray(myEvents, info.event.extendedProps.eventID);
          info.el.style.borderColor = 'transparent';
      }
      else
      {
          addToEventArray(info.event.extendedProps.eventID);
          info.el.style.borderColor = 'red';
      }
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('clicked single event');
    }
  }
```

I hope this comes in handy for someone else out there.